# codeigniter page not found 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

I'm working on website that made by someone else using codeIgniter, when I upload it on my local server it says object not found so I added the .htacess file to remove the index.php from the link

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and I faced another issue which is the page display 404 page not found (not the same issue before it)
and my config file like this,
 base_url :

```
$root  = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

index page:
`$config['index_page'] = '';`

uri protocol:
`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';`

and it's work when I add "index.php" in the link.

Comment: so I decided to try it on new project (that have only welcome page) and it works by adding .htacess  file that what make me confuse

Comment: Add this piece of information to a new answer instead of a comment and set it as the "accepted answer" by ticking it.

Comment: The problem still not solved yet, because it worked for me when I start new project folder, but still has the same issue in the one that I working on

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in .htaccess and config

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';

or

$config['base_url'] = 'put-here-your-local-ip';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Xampp check your project folder
in your htaccess file you have to set RewriteBase to your folder name

```
RewriteBase /YOUR_PROJECT/
```

check your config file in application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url']  =  "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';
```

check route file in application/config/route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'YOUR_Control_NAME';
```